# Is what my grammar book says relevant? the interchangeability of future simple and future continuous with certain designations of time

Tags: future-time, future-constructions, future-continuous

I have a book called "The practice of English grammar." by Izrailevich, Katchalova. It's quite old.

I wonder whether what it says is true and accurate. Is it really true that you use *the simple future tense* with these designations of time interchangeably with *the future continuous tense*?

It says in paragraph § 27 that *the future continuous tense* is sometimes used alongside with *the future simple tense* with such designations of time as **all day long**, **all day tomorrow**, **all the time**, **the whole evening**, **from five till six**, etc.

When the speaker uses *the future continuous tense* they show an action as *a process*, but when the speaker uses *the future simple tense* they just state *a fact* of doing the action.

Then it shows these examples:

> *"He will be reading the whole evening."*  and
> *"He will read the whole evening."*
>
> *"I shall be preparing for my examination all day tomorrow."*  and
> *"I shall prepare for my examination all day tomorrow."*
>
> "They will be working in the library from three till five."  and "They
> will work in the library from three till five."

Then it says that when an action with such a time designation is one of two or more consecutive actions, then only the future simple is used:

> *"I'll come home early, I'll rest from five till six, and then I'll work the whole evening."*

Comment: I can see no error there. You can use both "future simple"  (bad name) and future continuous with time expressions,  but the meaning is subtly different. That seems uncontroversial.

Comment: I would say that the future simple indicates a planned period of activity such as a period in a timetable, while the continuous tense indicates 'at any given moment during that time span, that is what you will find me doing'.

Comment: The last is rule seems too strict, and the example is a little odd.  (if you rest from 5 to 6, then you aren't working the whole evening).  It would be correct to say "I'll rest from 5 to 6, but then I'll be working the rest of the evening."

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with saying "I'll come home early, I'll be resting from five till six, and then [I'll be] working the whole evening."

Comment: @JamesK but what changes in the meaning?

Comment: What it says "When the speaker uses the future continuous tense they show an action as a process, but when the speaker uses the future simple tense they just state a fact of doing the action."

Comment: @JamesK Oh, right. I thought you meant something different. Does it really matter whether I want to show the action as a fact or as a process? My mother tongue doesn't make any distinctions here. Could I use both tenses to tell the same story? "My friends are coming at 6. We'll be having fun the whole evening. While we're watching a movie, my cat will be running around the flat like crazy." And "My friends are coming at 6. We'll have fun the whole evening. While we watch a movie, my cat will run around the flat like crazy."

Comment: Yes, The difference are subtle.  Shades of meaning rather than "right" and "wrong".

Comment: One unrelated addendum: shall in all of those examples is so archaic as to almost sound incorrect.

Comment: I disagree with @NickBailey. Mostly I say _I'll_ but if I say it more fully I'm as likely to say _I shall_ as _I will_.

Comment: Interesting! What's your dialect? I might be generalizing from west coast American English